# Use Flowplayer in Fancybox with absolute URLs

Tags: jquery, events, triggers, fancybox, flowplayer

I'm trying to use Flowplayer combined with Fancybox as shown in this example: http://demos.flowplayer.org/scripting/overlay-fancybox.html

When I implement it like that it works.

However, the href to the video is just written like an anchor:

```
<a href="#night1" class="fancybox">Video 1</a>
```

the rest of the URL is built in the script (also shown on the example page above)

However, I want it to link to the full video URL like this:

```
<a href="http://stream.flowplayer.org/night1/640x360.mp4" class="fancybox">Video 1</a>
```

When I alter the script to work with a full URL, it will open the video instead of using the fancybox.
I used `preventDefault()` to stop the anchors default action, but that also prevents the Fancybox from working. I somehow need to trigger the fancybox action to open the flowplayer.

Sorry for not providing a JSFiddle, but I don't think that I can include the flowplayer there.
The example linked in the beginning might help you.

### -

### -

-
This is the script based on a full length link as seen above:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".fancybox").click(function(event) {
    // don'T follow the video link
    event.preventDefault();


  // trigger the fancybox for the just clicked link and do as follows
  // this is whats not working, the fancybox is not getting triggered  
  $(this).fancybox({
    tpl: {
      // wrap template with custom inner DIV: the empty player container
      wrap: '<div class="fancybox-wrap" tabIndex="-1">' +
            '<div class="fancybox-skin">' +
            '<div class="fancybox-outer">' +
            '<div id="player">' + // player container replaces fancybox-inner
            '</div></div></div></div>'
    },

    beforeShow: function () {
      var base = this.href;
      base = base.substr(0, base.lastIndexOf('.'));

      // base should be the full length link without file extension now     
      alert(base);

      // install player into empty container
      $("#player").flowplayer({
        splash: true,
        ratio: 9/16,
        playlist: [
          [
            { webm: base + ".webm" },
            { mp4: base + ".mp4" },
            { ogg: base + ".ogv" },
            { flash: "mp4:" + base }
          ]
        ]
      });
      flowplayer("#player").play(0);

    },
    beforeClose: function () {
      // important! unload the player
      flowplayer("#player").unload();
    }
  });


  });
});
```

Comment: you can google it https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/fancybox/htaARTaDfsE or https://gist.github.com/franciscoj/571643 or http://www.burconsult.com/tutorials/fp2/

Comment: These solutions use the old flowplayer, I am using the new one which uses flash video only as a fallback and tries to use the html 5 video tag with various file formats instead.
For my situation it should be enough to find a way to trigger the Fancybox from a click event. I'll add some lines to my question.

Comment: to trigger fancybox after a click event, in your code above replace this `$(this).fancybox()` by this `$.fancybox()`

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

A working solution for me is the replacement of the href on hover:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var url = window.location;
    var prot = window.location.protocol;
    var host = window.location.host;
    var path = window.location.pathname;

    var videoclip='';
    var filename='';

    $(".videobox").hover(function(){
        videoclip=$(this).attr('href');
        filename = videoclip.substring(videoclip.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        filename = filename.substr(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
        $(this).attr({"href":"#"+filename });
    },function(){
        $(this).attr({"href":""+videoclip+""});
    });

    $('.videobox').fancybox({
        tpl: {
          // wrap template with custom inner DIV: the empty player container
          wrap: '<div class="fancybox-wrap" tabIndex="-1">' +
                '<div class="fancybox-skin">' +
                '<div class="fancybox-outer">' +
                '<div id="player">' + // player container replaces fancybox-inner
                '</div></div></div></div>' 
        },

        beforeShow: function () {
          var base = this.href.slice(1),
              cdn = prot + "//" host + path;

          // install player into empty container
          $("#player").flowplayer({
            splash: true,
            ratio: 9/16,
            qualities: "360p,480p,720p,1080p",
            defaultQuality: "360p",
            rtmp: "rtmp://s3b78u0kbtx79q.cloudfront.net/cfx/st",
            playlist: [
                [
                    { mpegurl: cdn + base + ".m3u8" },
                    { webm: cdn + base + ".webm" },
                    { mp4: cdn + base + ".mp4" },
                    { flash: "mp4:" + base + ".mp4" }
                ]
            ]
          });
          flowplayer("#player").play(0);

        },
        beforeClose: function () {
          // important! unload the player
          flowplayer("#player").unload();
        }
    });

});
```

works in all major browsers I tested it with.